# AngularJS and WebApi POST getting null in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make a POST to a web api server. The controller looks like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    string a = value;
}
```

And the angular $resource and controller:

```
$scope.makeLoan = function(){
    var cartData = CartFactory.cartData;
    LoanFactory.save(JSON.stringify(cartData));
}

.factory('LoanFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/loan/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
        {"update" : {method:"PUT"}}
    );
});
```

**The problem is that I am getting null in the "a" string, same as value.**
I tried sending a pure string from angular, but the result is the same.
What could be the problem, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In save use hash .save({id: value_to_send})

```
LoanFactory.save({id:JSON.stringify(cartData)});
```

Comment: This way I get a `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).` from the server

Comment: You can try pass json on save call, in the resource use transformRequest  and use JSON.stringify(). Here link to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 0):

The comment explains better:

```
.factory('LoanFactory', function ($resource) {
 return $resource('/api/loan/:id',
    {id: '@id'},
    {"update" : {method:"PUT"}},
    {save: 
         {transformRequest: function(data){
              return JSON.stringify(data);
         }}
 );
});
```